Is Carnot theorem applicable to black holes?
As I know, there is a simple method to take almost all $mc^2$ from mass by dropping it to the black hole. Doesn't this violate Carnot theorem? Or does it define the temperature of black hole as very low?

May I ask for a reference to such method? I suspect that it has nothing to do with thermodynamic (where Carnot theorem is applied to).

This isn't a complete answer but you can think in this direction: when you drop a mass into a BH , it will radiate GW because now essentially you have a two body system coalescing into one another and radiation does take away energy, angular momentum etc. So BH doesn't eat all of the mass

Is this related to e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.3342 where black holes are "mined" using cosmic strings? There is no thermodynamic reason one cannot convert mass into energy, and in the case of black holes it is energy, not work, that is extracted. Carnot only limits useful work, waste heat is fine.

I believe the asker to be referring to the Penrose process. Though, "almost all" $mc^2$ here is really more like $1/5$.

No, Penrose process is a bit overcomplicating. I am just referring to dropping some mass to BH with rope mounted to it. This rope will pull the turbine

The rope will break. There is another process that works for a Schwarzchild black hole, and it is something like 9% or so.

But we can obtain a lot of energy before it breaks

The rope will break almost instantly.

it doesn't look like fundamental explanation

My understanding is the Carnot efficiency applies to a cyclic process converting heat flow to work. It would not apply to a one-time lowering of a mass into a potential well, whether that well is around the Earth or a BH.

But we can built a cyclic process and repeatedly lower different masses into BH. We can apply Carnot theorem for diesel engines as well, even if we throw away the fuel after ignition


Is Carnot theorem applicable to black holes?

Black holes are thermodynamical systems, so yes, Carnot's theorem is applicable to systems containing black holes.

As I know, there is a simple method to take almost all $mc^2$
from mass by dropping it to the black hole.

Assuming the scheme outlined by OP in comments, lowering mass into the black hole on a rope with the other end attached to a turbine and then dropping it, the efficiency of this conversion would increase the closer to the horizon the mass is lowered and in the (unreachable) limit of the dropping point being infinitesimally close to the horizon the efficiency indeed would approach $100\ \%$.

Doesn't this violate Carnot theorem?

No. Because Carnot's theorem does not apply here: once the mass is
dropped into the black hole the system changes, you no longer have a mass, so it is not a cyclic, repeatable process.
To make a heat engine out of this energy conversion scheme let us introduce a thermal reservoir at a temperature $T_1$ thermally insulated from the black hole. We put our mass (which we choose so that it could store some quantity of thermal energy) in contact with this reservoir so that it absorbs that thermal energy and then lower this mass on a rope toward the black hole. But we do not drop the mass, instead we leave it hanging near the horizon allowing it to cool off through thermal radiation (which would be absorbed by the black hole) and then pull the mass (which would be lighter now) back up. The net effect is as if we lowered and then dropped off into the black hole some excess thermal energy. The cycle could then be repeated, thus making this scheme a cyclic process.
But black hole also has a temperature: $T_\text{bh}$, this is the temperature of Hawking radiation that a distant observer would register.  If we consider a static observer close to the black hole for whom time goes at a rate $\alpha$ ($\alpha<1$) relative to a distant one, then such an observer would register the temperature $T_\text{bh} \alpha^{-1}$ (higher than the distant observer), and the closer to a black hole horizon, the higher the observed temperature. For a mass from the previous paragraph to be able to cool off its temperature must be higher than the temperature of Hawking radiation surrounding it, so there is a minimal height above the horizon at which the mass can lose thermal energy, if we lower it any more it would be absorbing thermal energy. This minimal height also limits efficiency of conversion of thermal energy to work to precisely that of Carnot heat engine:
$$\eta_\text{max}=\frac{T_1-T_\text{bh}}{T_1}.$$
This is not surprising, since this cycle (if we optimize it) becomes a Carnot cycle in disguise: first the mass absorbs thermal energy from hot reservoir, for maximum efficiency this must happen precisely at $T_1$ (possibly via  latent heat of some phase transition). Then the mass is adiabatically lowered toward the black hole to the point where its temperature ($T_1$ its own frame) becomes equal to the temperature of black hole's thermal radiation measured at that point. Then thermal energy is released by the mass (again for maximum efficiency isothermally at temperature $T_1$ at the position of the mass, but that temperature is actually a $T_\text{bh}$ when viewed by distant observer). And then the mass  is raised adiabatically back. So, two isothermal and two adiabatic processes: Carnot cycle.
A more detailed discussion of heat engines involving black holes could be found here:

Opatrný, T., & Richterek, L. (2012). Black hole heat engine. American Journal of Physics, 80(1), 66-71, doi:10.1119/1.3633692, free pdf.


Thank you very much. I thought again and dropping mass to BH is really acyclic process compared to car engine for example. So Carnot theorem is not appicable to BH.

Lowering mass m to a black hole with mass M has the same efficiency as a machine that consists of ideal solar-panel, a black hole with mass m, and an other black hole with mass M. The ideal solar-panel reaches an efficiency that is the Carnot-efficiency when the two temperatures are the two temperatures of the two black holes. The two temperatures change as the machine is working. I have a simple python script that simulates that machine, I can post it, if interested. The "solar-panel" produces electricity from Hawking radiation, radiated by the smaller black hole, bigger black hole is the heat sink.
The efficiency can be increased by chopping the mass to small pieces and lowering them one by one, obviously not if the mass is a black hole. The reason is that smaller masses can be lowered closer to the horizon, before the horizon expands towards the mass.
There must be a limit of how much the efficiency can be increased by the aforementioned chopping method. I mean a limit that prevents the Carnot-limit to be exceeded. It might work like this: If an object has high heat capacity and lot of heat energy, then it has high entropy. And when chopped to very small pieces the heat capacity decreases, so the object heats up, so a chopper is a heat pump, so it must use energy, which decreases the total efficiency.

I found the effective GTR potential
$$U_f(r)=-\frac{GMm}{r}+\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}-\frac{GML^2}{mc^2r^3}$$
and for event horizon
$$r_g=\frac{2GM}{c^2}=\frac{2\mu}{c^2}$$
it will give no more than half of $mc^2$ energy from falling body of mass $m$. But it still rise a question about temperature of black hole. If efficiency of BH can be 50%, then we somehow can define temperature of BH via Carnot theorem
